# Cómo eliminar duplicidades en una consulta

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos con postgressql y el plugin postgis, una columna de tipo jsonb donde guardo las propiedades de un geojson.

He creado una consulta para obtener de dicha columna, properties que es de tipo jsonb, para que me devuelva el nombre de la propiedad y su tipo.

Mi problema es que en una misma fila puede tener valores null o de otro tipo como string o number.

Cómo puedo hacer para que no me duplique las filas que son null y otro tipo al mismo tiempo??

Saludos

Esta es la consulta:

```
select json_data.key, jsonb_typeof(json_data.value) 
from tabla x, 
jsonb_each(x.properties) as json_data group by key, 
jsonb_typeof order by key, jsonb_typeof;
```

Y esto es lo que me devuelve, para que os hagáis una idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner un `WHERE` diciéndole que no quieres registros nulos para `json_data.value` con la condición `is not null`

```
select json_data.key, jsonb_typeof(json_data.value) 
from tabla x, 
jsonb_each(x.properties) as json_data 
where jsonb_typeof(json_data.value) is not null
group by key
order by key;
```

Comment: no funciona.. devuelve lo mismo, filas duplicadas con el mismo nombre una de tipo string y otra de tipo null... vamos lo mismo que en la imagen

Comment: Prueba con `jsonb_typeof(json_data.value) is not null`. Puede que el valor no sea `null` pero su tipo si lo sea, lo que sería extraño. Por otra parte cambiaremos el `group by`. Cambio la respuesta.